# How to modify character value exactly as when check.names option in read.table is enabled in R?

Tags: r, file-io, read.table

I want to select columns from a `data.frame` `df` according to some vector `x` of column names. The problem is that I read `data.frame` from a file using `read.table()` and it modifies colnames that are in the file. What I want is to modify vector `x` exactly as colnames were modified in `df` when I read it using `read.table()`. Is there such function in R or is there better way to deal with this problem? I know I could set `check.names=FALSE` in `read.table` but I would rather have colnames checked.

Example. The file is

```
some-column1    some-column2
value           value
value           value
value           value
```

After `read.table` columns are modified like

```
some.column1    some.column2
value           value
value           value
value           value
```

When I try to select a column from `df` using vector `x = c('some-column1')` like `df[,x]` I select nothing since column names were modified. I want to run some function `check.names()` that `check.names(x) == c('some.column1')`.

Comment: Can you add some example data to make what you're asking more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `make.names()`: from the description of `check.names` in `?read.table`:

> `check.names` ... If necessary [the names] are adjusted (by make.names) so that they are [syntactically valid] ...

```
make.names(c("(Intercept)","weird stuff","1more"))
## [1] "X.Intercept." "weird.stuff"  "X1more"
```

If you want handle duplicated names you need to specify `unique=TRUE` to `make.names()`:

```
read.table(header=TRUE,text="
a&b 1more dup dup
1   2     3   4
")
## a.b X1more dup dup.1
## 1   1      2   3     4
make.names(c("a&b","1more","dup","dup"), unique=TRUE)
## [1] "a.b"    "X1more" "dup"    "dup.1"
```

Comment: Luckily, I do not expect duplicates, but I will keep that in mind, thank you @BenBolker

Comment: And now I see your workaround for duplicates as well: `unique=TRUE`

Comment: I decided to look at the code of `read.table` to see what it was doing to handle duplicates ...